# Child process of an Azure DevOps task is killed when the job stops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I have a custom PowerShell Azure DevOps task that creates a child process (for another PowerShell script). **I want the child process to run for a while - it's a background polling job. However, the child process is stopped when the custom task finishes.**

I've isolated that to a bare minimum example. The main task script goes:

```
$PollScriptPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, "poll.ps1")
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c powershell.exe $PollScriptPath  >PollLog.txt 2>&1"
```

Poll.ps1 does nothing in the example, just sits there for 5 minutes:

```
Write-Host Hello
Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
```

The task executor is the legacy Powershell host; the relevant part in the task manifest goes: `{"execution":{"PowerShell":{...}}}`

To check, I've added a 30 second sleep after the `Start-Process` line; with that in place, I can see the powershell process running in the context of the agent account for as long as the PS host process is running. When the latter quits, the former quits too.

Could this have to do with console ownership? E. g. the child process inherits the console from the parent, when the parent quits destroys the console, the child has to quit too. Or is this about somehow about process hierarchy? Or could it be that the powershell host has logic in place to intercept spawned processes and terminate them?

---

EDIT: couple more data points. The scope of spawned process lifetime is a TFS job, not a task. I've added another task with a minute-long delay, and the spawned PowerShell process would stay alive for the execution of that also. For one thing, this means that both the modern PowerShell executor, and the Node executors would exhibit a similar behavior regarding spawned processes.

Also, they are, very likely, **not** using Windows job objects to manage the lifetime of the process. The Task Manager on the agent machine doesn't display a Job ID for any of those processes. Could be that the job object is too secured for the admin to see its mere existence, though. Jobs would be a natural, Windows native way to control the lifetime of a process tree...

It's not console driven. I've started the agent interactively - spawned cmd.exe gets its own window. Still quits when the job terminates.

Deliberately orphaning a process (a starts b and waits for a bit, b starts c and quits immediately) doesn't work, either. Judging by the Process Explorer, when b quits, c moves in the process tree underneath a, which leaves it vulnerable to the tree termination logic.

---

One way to cheat the process tree is outlined here: https://scorpiosoftware.net/2021/01/10/parent-process-vs-creator-process/

The idea is:

- Create/initialize a PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST object with 1 attribute
- Put a PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS there, specifying a process handle to a fake parent
- Put said object into `lpAttributeList` of a `STARTUPINFOEX` structure
- Create a child process with `dwCreationFlags` having `EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT`, passing said structure

Needless to say, this deep magic is not exposed to PowerShell's `Start-Process`. Also, at the first stab, it doesn't work for this question's purposes.

Comment: Everything you're describing is intentional behavior that's by design. Can you explain what you're actually trying to do? Because starting long-running background activities is *not* what pipelines are for.

Comment: I'd like to initiate an Active Directory TLS certificate enrollment that won't complete synchronously (it's the policy), and poll for results. I don't control the CA neither technically nor organizationally, and lobbying for a change in the issuance policy is way above my pay grade.

Comment: The better choice for asynchrony is to add a gate using the Invoke REST API step. How you set it up is going to differ depending on whether you're using YAML or classic pipelines, but the idea is the same: Start the process however you want, then let the API polling happen by Azure Pipelines between jobs.

Comment: The check is trickier than a mere REST call. Also, I need to sell this flow to a sizable software shop; ease of implementation is a priority.

Comment: Then Azure Pipelines may not be the appropriate tool for the job here. Steps generally can't have side effects on the agent (aside from the file system, and even then the file system can't be expected to persist beyond the scope of a job).

Answer (score 0):

After some attempts to escape the sandbox, I've set up a scheduled task on the agent machine with no triggers, and the task script would start it with `Start-ScheduledTask`. The polling script had to be somewhat rewritten to service a set of delayed requests rather than just one.

Note that the scheduled task has a set on credentials on it that doesn't necessarily have to match the credentials on the agent service. In my case it has to and it does, since I've taken care to set it up this way, but in the general case, it's something to think of. A script executing in the AzDevOps agent doesn't automagically have access to the agent service's Windows credentials.

I am not giving up on finding a way to escape the sandbox (it's a matter of pride now), but this will do. At least I am not springing any additional requirements on the task end users.